# How can I get Oaut2 token in salesforce for partner portal user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

How can I get Oauth2 token in salesforce for partner portal user?

User has Gold Partner liscence.

Comment: Do you have SSO enabled on your org?

Comment: Yes. SSO is enabled but not for partner portal users.